# Why does ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove require a second out argument?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I only want to remove a value.. I don't need to use the variable afterwards. Why not include an overload where this second parameter was not required?

Do I really have to just store it in a temporary local variable, not use it, and have the garbage collector collect it when the method ends? Seems rather silly..

The function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287129.aspx

Comment: How is the GC relevant here? It can collect the value once `TryRemove` returns.

Comment: I'm guessing: concurrency and strong exception guarantees. The interface is pure in that it returns the item exactly as it was removed: no information can get lost and the operation is undoable by definition. Think of value types as well.

Comment: @CodesInChaos GC of the unused `out value`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can create exactly the method you want:

```
public static class ConcurrentDictionaryEx {
  public static bool TryRemove<TKey, TValue>(
    this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> self, TKey key) {
    TValue ignored;
    return self.TryRemove(key, out ignored);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Or, as [Dialecticus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395718/dialecticus) mentioned in the comments, just use [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267289.aspx). But note that, since it's an explicit interface implementation, you'll need a reference to an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, which leads you back to creating an extension method if you want to avoid casting a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` reference:

```
public static class ConcurrentDictionaryEx {
  public static bool Remove<TKey, TValue>(
    this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> self, TKey key) {
      return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)self).Remove(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: Eh.. Why is this not included in the framework? I'm more curious as to why they would not simply include it by default.

Comment: Well, maybe they didn't think it was a common enough case to warrant a special case method. Maybe because it's so easy to derive it like the way I did. I don't really know.

Comment: @JohnSmith, TryRemove is used if you want to take the value and remove the key at the same time. If you don't care about the value then just use Remove.

Comment: @Dialecticus: good catch! I thought `Remove` would throw if the key wasn't found. I thought that the `TryRemove` indicated that, but I was wrong. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I just tried this solution out - works awesome 1+ from me, but how this code works is new to me. Can you please explain how the ConcurrentDictionary knows you are "extending" it by merely passing self as an arg? Is there some sort of article explaining this concept?

Comment: @MarzSocks: Those are called [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb383977.aspx). Take a read!

Comment: I use ConcurrentDictionary in multi threading case so I am wondering is it safe to use the remove method of IDictionary ?

Answer (score 85):

C#7 added discard syntactic sugar

So now you can write:

```
dictionary.TryRemove(entry.Key, out _);
```

[Reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/)

> We allow "discards" as out parameters as well, in the form of a _, to
>   let you ignore out parameters you don’t care about:
>
> `p.GetCoordinates(out var x, out _); // I only care about x`

Answer (score 12):

If you're not interested in the value that was removed, simply call `IDictionary.Remove(key)`. It's shadowed, so you have to invoke it explicitly.

Example:

```
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
dict.AddOrUpdate("mykey", (val) => "test", (val1, val2) => "test");
((IDictionary)dict).Remove("mykey");
```

The `TryRemove(key, out value)` method is there to give you feedback whether the operation made any change. Use the one that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 2nd argument is required is because you may need to do something with the item that you're removing from `ConcurrentDictionary`.

For example, imagine you have a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, MyDisposable>` where `MyDisposable` implements `IDisposable`. `ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove(...)` doesn't call `.Dispose();` on the item being removed from the dictionary.

In the code below, the `.Dispose();` call succeeds because the `MyDisposable` hasn't been disposed, yet.

```
void Main()
{
    var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, MyDisposable>();

    dict.TryAdd(1, new MyDisposable());

    dict.TryRemove(1, out var d);

    d.Dispose();
}

public class MyDisposable : IDisposable {

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~MyDisposable()
    // {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Now it has an overload that does not `out` any parameters:

```
public bool TryRemove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
```