# How to remove from ConcurrentDictionary if i dont want to get the value

Tags: c#, .net

it seems that ConcurrentDictionary only has a TryRemove method but no Remove method. Why is this?

I don't care about the value when i want to remove an entry by key. how can i do this?

Comment: Just remove the value and throw it away, as simple as that.

Comment: @Luaan: but i dont understand why it is necessary to provide a value at all.

Comment: @clamp, do you mean you want to know why `TryRemove()` passes the removed value back but `Remove()` does not?

Comment: You're not providing the value, it's an out parameter. It doesn't make a difference, except for slight clunkiness when you don't care about the value. Removing the value from the dictionary is already so much work it really doesn't matter whether it returns the value or not.

Comment: @clamp, then I would second sehe's comment [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464965/why-does-concurrentdictionary-tryremove-require-a-second-out-argument#comment9032248_7464965).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TryRemove` is native method of `ConcurrentDictionary`, whereas like with other collections, you do have an explicit implementation of `ICollection` with `Remove` method available:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287153%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

So `TryRemove` is a safe alternative to `Remove`, but you can choose between the two.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, ConcurrentDictionary is for use in multiple threads scenarios.

The lack of "Remove", and the existence of "TryRemove" is because two different threads may attempt to remove a specific item from the collection at the same time, but for obvious reasons only one can do it.

TryRemove tries to remove the item, but if the item is not found, no exception will happen.

Comment: there's no lack of `Remove`, it exists as implemenation of `ICollection`, as common implementation of collections. `TryRemove` is safe wrapper of `Remove`